# Makefile: where definition is defined

Tags: makefile

I'm building a third-party SDK where Makefile checks if DEF_2_3 was defined:

```
..
#ifdef DEF_2_3
CFLAGS_LOCAL += -I$(SDK)/include
#endif

all:
...
clean:
...
```

However, I didn't find anywhere in the SDK (I grepped through the directory), where DEF_2_3 would be defined. I wonder if makefile consideres ifdef MACRO as defined by default? And if so, I have to undefine MACRO at the top of the makefile.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Those are commented out.

make doesn't use `#ifdef` it uses `ifdef`.

See [7.2 Syntax of Conditionals](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Syntax).

> ifdef variable-name
>
> The ifdef form takes the name of a variable as its argument, not a reference to a variable. The value of that variable has a non-empty value, the text-if-true is effective; otherwise, the text-if-false, if any, is effective. Variables that have never been defined have an empty value. The text variable-name is expanded, so it could be a variable or function that expands to the name of a variable.